# Cannot get IIS pickup directory on Windows Server 2016 / IIS 10

Tags: c#, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am trying to send an email using C# on a Windows 2016 server, running IIS 10.
I installed IIS SMTP and it can send out messages using both Telnet and the windows pickup service.

Now I am using a C# webservice to send an email out.
At first I tried to use SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network like this:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "localhost";
```

however that resulted in this error:
Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25

So as the pickup service of the IIS SMTP (on C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup) is working I thought it would be best to just start using the pickup service.

Using this code:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
```

However this results in a Cannot get IIS pickup directory error.

So in IIS Services manager under SMTP I check the bullet at 
"Store e-mail in pickup directory:"
And added C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup in the text field.

This didn't work however. 
So I also changed the web.config and added these lines:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
    <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup"  />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

This however didn't do the trick either. 
This will result in the following error:

```
Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path &#39;C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup\bb3fc5af-e213-43d3-af47-cb2836de78c3.eml&#39;.
```

I still get the same error and don't know how to fix this.

Could you please help out?

Best regards

Comment: client.Host = "localhost";...have you tried specifying the same host name you configured for the smtp.

Comment: Just tried it and results into: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Comment: Do you require SSL/TLS? If Telnet works then SmtpClient should work using same host/port.

Comment: SSL is not required telnet will work on telnet localhost 25

Comment: That's weird the "Unable to read data from the transport connection" error looks it would be incompatible tls settings between client and server.

Comment: Could it be an anti-virus program blocking your connection?

Comment: Just a thought. If you're using the default mail server, [ SMTP Virtual Server #n ], for pickup on your server. You might get it to work by setting the IP address on the mail server to (All Unassigned). Also, you are aware that you have to provide your login credentials via the available options, either in the mail server properties dialog or the web.config file, or both.

Comment: I will check the anti virus program, it could be just it. As all other connections do work.

Comment: Yes I tried switching between ALL Unassigned to the IP of the server, both settings result in the same errors.

As I setup the mail server to be relaying (only for the ip addresses on the server) I should be able to not use a username and password sending out email. 

The same settings by the way do work for a 2012 server with the same code and installations.

Comment: It's not the anti virus program, we disabled it and still we cannot sent out mails with IIS / C#

Comment: As follow up to the last `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Maybe too obvious, but because you didn't mention; does the account/identity configured on the `ApplicationPool` have write (and read) rights to that folder? IIS often gives a not-found-alike error instead of eg. access-denied.

Comment: For the 2nd solution are you sure that that path exist? 
'C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup\' <-- If yes (just for testing purpose obviously) try to give the folder permission of fullcontrol for user 'everyone'. If it works your server may aver some problem with doimain authentication.
L-

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work.
Eventually I just brought everything back to it origin and started over.

It works now, but what it is exactly I don't know for sure.